# How to install aws-cfn-bootstrap in AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

Im building an Ubuntu AMI using packer. In packer.json, i install aws-cfn-bootstrap like this:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install -t /opt/aws https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
```

It will have all cfn script in /opt/aws/bin

However, when i run

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource AutoscaleGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
```

I have this error

```
ImportError: No module named cfnbootstrap
```

Im not sure what's going on here. The reason I dont use easy_install is because i encounter this error with easy_install

```
Couldn't find index page for 'pystache' (maybe misspelled?)
```

Anybody help please?

Comment: because you're doing a `-t` install you're not going to have all the dependencies on the `sys.path`.  you _could_ use `PYTHONPATH` but I would personally just drop `-t` and then get things in `/usr/local/bin` *or* set up a virtualenv and install it into that

Comment: weird thing. pip doesnt install cfn binaries to /usr/local/bin by default. I guess.i have to move them to /usr/local/bin